# How Can I Define IP Address Field in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint

I'm creating a list using visual studio 2010, I want the list to contains I-P-Address field which i figured out is not available out of the box, so i guess i need to define that field.

how can i define that field type pro-grammatically?

Edit: I followed the tutorial [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2012/02/05/developing-custom-field-type-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx) to create Custom Field but when i was adding list from visual studio i tried to change type to Ip Address but i couldnt find it!

[image: Image here showing that i cant find it in Type]

thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is Visual Studio 2010 you are using. A list wizard like you are showing is not part of VS2010, but rather one of the upcoming features of the new Visual Studio - or you might be using some Add-In. You will most probably not be able to see your custom field type in a dropdown box like that in any case. You can use the regular declerative way to create a list with your fieldtype (or programatically).

Comment: Yep, there is no IP address type which is why you were creating a new custom field type. What is your actual question?

Comment: @moontear, oops sorry your right im using visual studio 11, it was just a typo , im used to type visual studio 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is Visual Studio 2010 you are using. A list wizard like you are showing is not part of VS2010, but rather one of the upcoming features of the new Visual Studio - or you might be using some Add-In. You will most probably not be able to see your custom field type in a dropdown box like that in any case. You can use the regular declerative way to create a list with your fieldtype (or programatically).

In short: Use the declerative way (or programmatic way) to declare your list. VS 11 won't be able to show your custom field type - that would be pretty magic as your field type could do pretty much anything (custom field renderers, validation etc.) - no way you could just "display" that in a wizard.